# FFT energy calculation by frequency

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing, fast-fourier-transform

For a FFT result in frequencies $k$ and associated amplitude magnitude $A(k)$ it is possible to calculate the signal energy by:
$E=\sum_{k=1}^{N} A(k)^2  $

However, what does it mean when the energy is multiplied by the current frequency $k$ such as:

$E=\sum_{k=1}^{N} k\:A(k)^2  $

I thought it is a way to calculate frequency energy, but cannot find any source doing it this way.
If it is a viable calculation, is there a name for this method?

Comment: If $A(k)$ is the amplitude of the signal with frequency $k$, then $kA(k)$ is the amplitude of its derivative. Therefore $k\left(A(k)\right)^{2}$ has something to do with multiplication of signal and its derivative, which is related to derivative of a square of a signal.

Comment: But it not seems a usual processes, I will restrain to first definition.